# "ModelImporterClipAnimation" Settings don't get applied to FBX

Tags: unity, animation, import

I am trying to edit animation file settings in the FBX file. I managed to load the file and extract animation clip names using the code below, however, I am unable to actually edit any of the settings of the FBX via script.

I am not able to pin point any specific issues with my code as it's not throwing any null errors and properly returning debug information.

Any help is appreciated!

```html
    public void SetupAnimations(string path)
    {
        ModelImporter modelImporter = (ModelImporter)AssetImporter.GetAtPath(path);
        modelImporter.importAnimation = true;
        ModelImporterClipAnimation clip = GetModelImporterClip(modelImporter);

        Debug.Log(clip.takeName);
        clip.loopTime = true;
        clip.mirror = true;
        clip.ConfigureClipFromMask(bothHandsAvatarMask);
    }

    static ModelImporterClipAnimation GetModelImporterClip(ModelImporter mi)
    {
        ModelImporterClipAnimation clip = null;
        if( mi.clipAnimations.Length == 0 )
        {
            //if the animation was never manually changed and saved, we get here. Check defaultClipAnimations
            if( mi.defaultClipAnimations.Length > 0 )
            {
                clip = mi.defaultClipAnimations[0];
                Debug.Log("Getting Default Animations");
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogError("GetModelImporterClip can't find clip information");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            clip = mi.clipAnimations[0];
            Debug.Log("Getting Changed Animations");

        }
        return clip;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Select all animation fbx, go to Animation Tab and enable Custom Properties, Hit Apply,
2. This step will create the clipAnimations: meta file in .meta files.
3. Use the following code to do the changes, here I am using the changes needed by me but you can use the changes you need. `using System.IO;
   using UnityEditor;
   using UnityEngine;

public class AnimationModifier : MonoBehaviour
{
public string rootFolderPath = "Assets/Models";  // Specify the root path where to start looking for model files.
public ModelImporterAnimationCompression animationCompression = ModelImporterAnimationCompression.Off;

```
public bool importAnimation = true;

[ContextMenu("Modify Animations")]
public void ModifyAnimations()
{
    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(rootFolderPath, "*.fbx", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
    {
        string assetPath = filePath.Replace("\\", "/");  // Convert Windows-style paths to Unity-style paths
        ModelImporter modelImporter = AssetImporter.GetAtPath(assetPath) as ModelImporter;
        modelImporter.importAnimatedCustomProperties = true;
        modelImporter.SaveAndReimport();
        modelImporter.importAnimatedCustomProperties = false;
        if (modelImporter != null)
        {
            if (modelImporter.clipAnimations != null && modelImporter.clipAnimations.Length > 0)
            {
                var name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(assetPath);
                var clip = modelImporter.clipAnimations[0];
                clip.firstFrame = 0;
                clip.name = name;
                clip.takeName = name;
                clip.loopTime = true;
                clip.keepOriginalPositionXZ = true;
                clip.keepOriginalPositionY = true;
                clip.keepOriginalOrientation = true;
                clip.lockRootRotation = true;
                clip.lockRootHeightY = true;
                clip.lockRootPositionXZ = true;
                modelImporter.clipAnimations = new []{clip};
            }

            modelImporter.animationCompression = animationCompression;
            modelImporter.importAnimation = importAnimation;
            modelImporter.SaveAndReimport();
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("No model found at " + assetPath);
        }
    }
}
```

}
`